# Java - Splitting String based on multiple delimiters

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

I essentially want to split up a string based on the sentences, therefore (for the sake of what I'm doing), whenever there is a `!`, `.`, `?`, `:`, `;`.

How would I achieve this with multiple items to split the array with?

Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

[`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) takes a regex to split on, so you can simply:

```
mystring.split("[!.?:;]");
```

Answer (score 8):

[Guava's](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) [`Splitter`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Splitter.html) is a bit [more predictable](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained#Splitter) than `String.split()`.

```
Iterable<String> results = Splitter.on(CharMatcher.anyOf("!.?:;"))
   .trimResults() // only if you need it
   .omitEmptyStrings() // only if you need it
   .split(string);
```

and then you can use `Iterables.toArray` or `Lists.newArrayList` to wrap the output results how you like.

Answer (score 6):

The argument of String.split is a regex, so you can create a pattern that matches any of those characters.

```
s.split("[.!:;?]");
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [String.split(String regex)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) method with parameter `"[!.?:;]"`.