# String split two delimiters

Tags: java, split

I'm actually making an app in which I have a text area where the user can write in my little "language", nothing hard, the user can write the following lines:

`game:`

`i>5;`

`i<8;`

`player:`

`name=Player 1;`

So I concatenate it, lower case it, which gives me the following string: `"game:i>5;i<8;player:name=player1;"`

Which must give me here two Request objects,

`new Request("game", "i>5;i<8")`

`new Request("player", "name=player1");`

Here's an example below

[image]

```
String string = "ygu:tezr;tt;:zertrtrr.etrvz1;tzej:j;ii;,k;i,:kik,;:k:,;ab:";
String part1, part2;
ArrayList<Request> list = new ArrayList<Request>();
/*while(?){
    part1 = ?
    part2 = ?
    list.add(new Request(part1, part2));
}*/
```

Thanks in advance! :D

Comment: What do you mean by "or"? Do you want to split your string using both of them(":" and ";") or one of them is root split like first split using ";" and then each substring using ":" or vice versa?

Comment: you want to split by `:` and then each one split by `;` to have pairs that's it ?

Comment: Most probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9149918/java-splitting-string-based-on-multiple-delimiters

Comment: In fact i'm having a hard time explaining ti clearly, that's probably why I can't do it myself, but I'll do my best to explain in some sentences

Comment: you may detail a bit because there are some ";" that are not used for delimiter in your example, you can split on "some ;" ^^

Comment: I edited my post, in fact yesterday I made the trick going from the end to the start of the string, it worked but in some cases it didn't, couldn't work it out so I decided I had to do it in the order the user read, so left to right

Comment: If you want this to be extendable to a more complex form later on, you have to write your own `parser` instead of using just string split.

Comment: `string.split(":|;");` ?

Comment: Add a character used to separate the two request objects in the code you require. Then it'll be much easier.

Comment: sercanturkmen that's what I'm doing, but it wont be more than what I wrote there, I'm doing the next part where i make sure labels (part1) and core (part2) are the right form, but first I need to split the body into logical parts, it was so boring that I worked on my next mission: I finished the method telling me if the given label is acceptable James McDowell good idea i'll try it out

Comment: I'd also recommend Guava for its [`Splitter`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/StringsExplained) class, which sounds relevant here.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the standard format that you mentioned above then you can use following code to get the data -

```
String s = "game:i>5;i<8;player:name=player1;";
String[] requests = s.split(";");

System.out.println(requests[0].split(":")[0]+"  "+requests[0].split(":")[1]+";"+requests[1]);
System.out.println(requests[2].split(":")[0]+"  "+requests[2].split(":")[1]);
```

This is just to give you an idea on how you can break the string.

This what I get as an output when I run the above code -

Output

```
game  i>5;i<8                                                                                                                                          
player  name=player1
```